# Unable to Update/Insert Oracle Bfiles - Read Only

Tags: oracle11g, bfile

I have Bfile filed in ORACLE db. While inserting data it is throwing following error

Unable to Update/Insert Oracle Bfiles - Read Only

Two days before same setup was working for last 6 months.

We have created bfile directory on shared path and same path is mounted properly on all the servers.

Please let me know if any one having any  solution for the same.

Regards,
Vikas Hirwani